# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException with the presence of Locks

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, concurrentmodification, locks

I have the following setup initially

```
LinkedList<Integer> ll;
Lock lock; 
...
//memory is allocated
ll = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

Then in a Timer thread, I have the following

```
Integer example... //set somewhere before
lock.lock();
ll.addLast(example);
lock.unlock();
```

Another in another Timer thread, have the following

```
ListIterator<Integer> ll_iter = new ll.listIterator();
while (ll_iter.hasNext()){
  //do something then
  lock.lock();
  ll_iter.remove();
  lock.unlock();
}
```

I get the following error when running
`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

These two locations are the only places that the list is accessed, has anything added or removed. However, very sporadically, I get the following error. I can't find why this is happening? Is it because of the iterator? Both locks are in a timer threar (Java Timer with a run method, period etc).

Comment: You are modifying the list while iterating. Lock the list, then iterate and unlock after iteration is done.

Comment: Shouldn't the lock stop both of them adding/removing concurrently?

Comment: It does. But iteration itself is unprotected. You are adding elements to the list while iterating.